# Can an unfeasible solution be optimal in an LPP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

In a linear programming problem, Is it possible to have an unfeasible solution that is optimal?

Comment: No. An optimal solution must be first feasible, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

No. An optimal solution must be first feasible, by definition.